# Definition with word to be defined instead of counter

Tags: newtheorem, definition

I know the title is a bit weird but I'll try to explain it in a better way here.
In the beginning of a chapter I'd like to define some basic terms. Currently I'm using

```
\newmdtheoremenv{mydef}{Definition}
```

which results in the following:[image]

Is there an easy way to do it without "Definition 1."  but "Machine Learning" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdframed` lacks the possibility to define unnumbered theorems, but it's not difficult to add it.

Next, a common trick for a variable label can be applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\NewDocumentCommand\newmdtheoremenvnonumber{O{} m m }{%
  \newtheorem*{#2}{#3}
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{#2}{%
     \begin{mdframed}[#1]}%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{#2}{%
     \end{mdframed}}%
}

\newmdtheoremenvnonumber{mydefinner}{\mydeflabel}
\newcommand{\mydeflabel}{}
\newenvironment{mydef}[1]
 {\renewcommand\mydeflabel{#1}\begin{mydefinner}}
 {\end{mydefinner}}

\newcommand{\attribution}[1]{\textup{(#1)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydef}{Machine Learning}
Machine learning is the field of study that gives computers
the ability to learn without being explicitly programmed.
\attribution{Arthur Samuel, 1959}.
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]